# Printing the acronyms as well as the word(s) at the same time using the package acro

Tags: acronyms, acro

Using the package `acro`, I know how to print the acronym (just using `\ac{..}`) and how to print the entire word(s) in its long-form (just using `\acl{...`). How to print both the acronym and the entire word at the same time? I knew there was a way but I can't find it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found! On [this link](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/acronym/acronym.pdf), it is possible to find a document which lists all the option.

In my case, the right command is `\acf` which stands for Full Acronyms (words + acro).

Comment: The f stands for 'first', but yes, as doesn't change anything, as this is the solution I would have given.

Comment: thank you for point this out. I have through the document again (the one in the link in this same answer) and, pag. 2 line 6 it says:  " `\acf` *If later in the text again the Full Name of the acronym should be printed, use the command  acf to access the acronym.  It stands for “full acronym” and it always prints the fullname and the acronym in brackets.*"

Comment: I stand corrected. I could have sworn I had read somewhere in the documentation (although that was a couple years back) they said to use the "f" when one wanted to display the occurence as if it was the first time to use that acronym. I don't know if they changed it or I misremembered it. Anyways... carry on, nothing to see, here.

Comment: you are linking to the manual of the `acronym` package although your question was about the `acro` package. Luckily enough `acro` also has `\acf`…